# Read and reshape dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following csv file

```
Column1
" [1] ""offer1""  ""offer2"" ""offer3"" "
" [4] ""offer2"" ""offer2""  ""offer1"" "
" [7]  ""offer3""  ""offer1"" ""offer2"""
"[10] ""offer1""  ""offer2"" ""offer3"" "
```

I tried to import it in r using read.csv and readLines but the outcome is very messy
I would like to achieve the following dataframe

```
  Column1
1 offer1 
2 offer2
3 offer3
4 offer2
5 offer2
6 offer1
7 offer3
8 offer1
9 offer2
```

Comment: I couldn't understand the format of your csv file. Is it literally a .txt file with that exact writings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
> library(stringr)
> library(tidyr)
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% mutate(column1 = str_extract_all(column1, 'offer\\d+')) %>% separate_rows() %>% unnest(column1)
# A tibble: 12 x 1
   column1
   <chr>  
 1 offer1 
 2 offer2 
 3 offer3 
 4 offer2 
 5 offer2 
 6 offer1 
 7 offer3 
 8 offer1 
 9 offer2 
10 offer1 
11 offer2 
12 offer3 
>
```

Data used:

```
structure(list(column1 = " [1] \"\"offer1\"\"  \"\"offer2\"\" \"\"offer3\"\" \"\n            \" [4] \"\"offer2\"\" \"\"offer2\"\"  \"\"offer1\"\" \"\n            \" [7]  \"\"offer3\"\"  \"\"offer1\"\" \"\"offer2\"\"\"\n            \"[10] \"\"offer1\"\"  \"\"offer2\"\" \"\"offer3\"\" "), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
>
```

As Ricardo asked if you are looking for something else, then please add it in your question.